# pandas retain (modified) column order on write

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have some pandas code, I read in a CSV, then I add a column at the left (I believe that this is what is causing the problem), with:

```
cl.insert(0, 'CEPID', None)
```

Then I do some stuff (putting data into that column, adding a couple more rows, etc)

And then I write out the DF with:

```
cl.to_csv(toSendName, index = False)
```

I understand that the common solution seems to be to force the order of columns in the to_csv command, but I've got a LOT of columns, and I really feel like I shouldn't have to do that.

Or is something else going on?

ETA:

AHA! as per @Chrisaycock's suggestion, I put the write right after the insert, and it works as expected.

So, I guess more detail on the "other stuff" is necessary.

I have another csv with the same columns as the 1st, but only 2 rows. I append that DF to the bottom of the 1st one. Maybe it has something to do with that the 2nd doesn't have the added column when it's added?

Comment: I just ran an `insert()` and got the right order. What happens if you write immediately after the `insert()`? I.e., no other modifications.

Comment: What is the output order that you are looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for the order of the original file, except that the new column is 1st.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the 1st file had 4 empty columns that the 2nd didn't have, and that was breaking the append. I deleted those columns and it seems to work now!